# Rails - Get namespaced constant from Rails configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Suppose I have several implementations for a search engine.

```
module Searcher
  module Engine
    class Elasticsearch
    end

    class Algolia
    end
  end
end
```

I want a per-environment search engine configuration.

I declared the config in my environment (for some sort of Bridge Pattern)

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.search_engine = :elasticsearch
end
```

(Which I override in specific environment files)

Then in my search controller, I want to load the appropriate class according to the symbol I put in Rails.configuration.search_engine

```
@search_engine = Searcher::Engine::XXX
@search_engine.search
```

How do I resolve the full namespaced constant `Searcher::Engine::XXX` from the symbol `:elasticsearch` ?

EDIT :

```
Searcher::Engine.const_get(Rails.configuration.search_engine.to_s.titleize)
```

Does not work : it loads `Elasticsearch` (from the gem) and not `Searcher::Engine::Elasticsearch` (my own component)

```
::Searcher::Engine::Elasticsearch # => Searcher::Engine::Elasticsearch
Searcher::Engine.const_get(Rails.configuration.search_engine.to_s.titleize) # => Elasticsearch
Object.const_get("::Searcher::Engine::#{Rails.configuration.search_engine.to_s.titleize}") # => Elasticsearch
```

Ruby 2.3.0
Rails 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your search engines are all under `::Searcher::Engine`:

```
"::Searcher::Engine::#{Rails.configuration.search_engine.to_s.titleize}".constantize
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, it is still resolved to `Elasticsearch:Module` here... Typing `::Searcher::Engine::Elasticsearch` does work though, so the constant is really here.

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris that's strange... Try in rails console `Object.const_get(
  "::Searcher::Engine::#{'elasticsearch'.titleize}"
)`

Comment: `Object.const_get(  "::Searcher::Engine::Elasticsearch")
 => Elasticsearch`

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris.. just out of curiosity - what i you do either `Searcher::Engine.const_get(Rails.configuration.search_engine.to_s.titleize, false)` or `Object.const_get("::Searcher::Engine::#{Rails.configuration.search_engine.to_s.titleize}", false)` or `Object.qualified_const_get("::Searcher::Engine::#{Rails.configuration.search_engine.to_s.titleize}")` or `Searcher::Engine.qualified_const_get(Rails.configuration.search_engine.to_s.titleize)`?