# Check for presence of some parameter in a set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

My search engine retrieves some search filters from the parameters, but if there is no "filter" parameter I need to do something else.

I was previously doing

```
params.slice(*filter_params).any?
```

But I am now getting a

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Method any? is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1, as `ActionController::Parameters` no longer inherits from hash. Using this deprecated behavior exposes potential security problems. If you continue to use this method you may be creating a security vulnerability in your app that can be exploited. Instead, consider using one of these documented methods which are not deprecated: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.0.rc1/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html

I'm not sure what I can do to replace the `.any?` call here?

Comment: Hey, if any of the answers solved your issue please make sure to accept it. P.S. Did you try any of the things I've suggested in the comment to ma answer to [this your earlier questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39698466/1772830)? I just thought that `qualified_const_get` might be what you needed there (even though it is kinda late to the party)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can substitute it with [Object#`present?`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/present%3F):

```
params.slice(*filter_params).present?
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call `.to_h` on `params` to get the hash methods you're used to.

Comment: to me this sounds like a workaround rather than a solution :)

Comment: It's still a viable solution.  The OP's scenario isn't introducing security risk by using `.any?` and losing strong param's `@permitted` state, which is why the inheritance from Hash was removed in the first place: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/14384

Answer (score 0):

You could use !.blank? or !.empty?